# NuGet Installation of EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have been doing some testing between VS2015 and VS2017. I created a .NetFrameworkApp and a .NetCoreApp website in both systems. I then installed a couple of packages in all four websites; in particular EntitytFramework. It installed in both VS2015 websites and the VS2017 .NetFrameworkApp website without problem but it wouldn't install in the VS2017 .NETCoreApp website. I got the following error messages.

- net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
  Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'RLSBCWebSite_NC'.
  Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.4470850

  Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'RLSBCWebSite_NC'.         0

Anyone any idea why that should be. I am assuming it should install otherwise how would you use CodeFirst etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "EntityFramework" package is not supported with .NET Core App, use the:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

package instead

Comment: From the link you quote, I have used Nuget Package Manager and entered
<code>Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer</code>
and that has installed EF Core correctly.
Thanks for your help.